# recursive function that returns factorial C++

Tags: c++, function, recursion, factorial

I am trying to solve at the following exercise from the C++ Primer Plus book.

> Define a recursive function that takes an integer argument and returns
>   the factorial of that argument. Recall that 3 factorial, written 3!,
>   equals 3 × 2!, and so on, with 0! defined as 1. In general, if n is
>   greater than zero, n! = n * (n - 1)!. Test your function in a program
>   that uses a loop to allow the user to enter various values for which
>   the program reports the factorial.

I wrote the code that goes into main().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n);


int main()
{
    int number= 0;
    cout<<"Enter a number(0 to quit): ";
    while (cin >> number && number! = 0)
    {
        cout<< "Here is the factorial of the number: "<< factorial (number) << ". \n"
        "Enter next number(0 to quit): ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Now I can't think of a proper recursive function declaration. Can someone help  by writing the easiest (for someone new in programming) to grasp function declaration for this exercise?

Comment: Your declaration is acceptable.  Did you mean _definition_?

Comment: Give it a try. If you have a problem post it here.

Comment: Before you post here, enter your question title into your favorite search engines. This is a classic. You'll find dozens of examples and explanations already written out for you.

Comment: Your function declaration is just fine. Now you need a function **definition**. Start by describing in words how the calculation should go. Recursive functions usually have two parts: a bottom, which recognizes the end of the recursion and simply returns a value, and the recursion, which uses the function itself to calculate a simpler or smaller version of the target. So, generally, 0! is 1 (that's the bottom), and n! is n*(n-1)!.

Comment: As your quote from the book implies, `factorial(n)` should return 1 if n is 0, otherwise it should return `n * factorial(n-1)`.  If you are having trouble writing that as C++, you may be too far into the book.

Comment: Why on earth is this voted down? Who keeps voting these things down all the time?

Comment: @Mat Yes. I usually find the right stackoverflow page from a google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing a recursive algorithm to calculate the factorial of any number, we must first identify the **base case**, which is the part of the calculation that we can solve without recursion. That is the case where `n = 0` then `factorial(n) = 1`.

This tells how to solve the problem when `n`is equal to 0, but what do we do when `n` is greater than 0? That is the **recursive case**, or the part of the problem that we use recursion to solve. `If n > 0, then factorial(n) = n * factorial(n-1)`. This states that if n is greater than 0, the factorial of n is n times the factorial of `n-1`.

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1; // base case
    else
        return n * factorial(n-1); // recursive case
}
```

Comment: Let's see if I got it right. If for example   int factorial(5),   after going into 5 levels of recursion, the command line would have something like this: 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1...Then the program backs out through the same levels of recursion so we have: 1 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5. The product of all this is returned to the function call, right?

Comment: Yes, you are. A function call stack works like the _stack_ data structure. Learn about stacks and you'll have a better grasp on recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of:

```
int factorial(int n){
  if(n<=0)
    return 1;
  int num=factorial(n-1);
  if(num)
    return n*num;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use very short function as follows, but it the same as the answered provided by @superPhreshHackerKid

```
int factorial(int n){
    if (n > 0)
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    return 1;
}
```

Hope it helps